# Creating a variable with unequal rows

Tags: matlab

I want to create a variable that finds a pattern (let's say [1 1]) in different rows of a matrix (A). Of course there aren't an equal number of occurrences of this string in each row.

```
A = [ 0     0     0     1     1 
      1     1     1     0     0 
      0     1     0     1     1 
      1     1     1     0     0 
      0     1     0     0     1 
      1     0     1     1     1 
      0     1     0     1     0 
      1     1     1     0     1];
```

I could do:

```
for i = 1:n
    var(i,:) = strfind(A(i,:),[1 1]);
end
```

but then both sides of the equation won't be equal.

> ERROR: ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

I try to preallocate. I create a matrix with what I think would be the maximum number of occurrences of this string in each row of matrix A (let's say 50).

```
for i = 1:n
    var(i, :) = NaN(1,50)
end
```

That's followed by the previous bit of code and it's no good either.

I've also tried:

```
for i = 1:n
    var(i,1:numel(strfind(A(i,:),[1 1])) = strfind(A(i,:),[1 1])
end
```

> Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid
>   target for an assignment.

How should I go about doing this?

The output I expect is a matrix var(i,:) that gives me the position in the matrix where each of these patterns occur. It works fine for just one row.

For example:

```
var(1,:) = [1 2 5 8 10 22 48]
var(2,:) = [2 3 4 7 34 45 NaN]
var(3,:) = [4 5 21 32 33 NaN]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "no good"?  What error happens?
Also, what kind of output are you expecting? Can you give a sample `A` and a sample `var`?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this is intentional, but if your matrix is a matrix of integers, `[1 1]` is not a string; it's an array of numbers.  "Strings" in matlab refers to text, so `strfind` won't work in this situation.

Comment: in your for loop you have `strfind` twice on left-hand side.

Comment: You may want to look into cells.

Comment: @ Mohsen That was just an error here. My code has only one.

Comment: Your example `A` does not coincide with `var`. Also, preallocation should work be done outside of the loop: `var = NaN(n,50);`

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that I assumed it didn't really matter (only to demonstrate what it should look like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first try: you tried to build a matrix with different length of rows.

In your second try: you pre-allocated, but then run it over by re-definning `var(i,:)`, while you tried to put there your desired result.

In your third try: unfortunately you just missed one brackets-  `)` at the end of left expression.

This code suppose to work (what you did at 2nd and 3rd attempts, with pre-allocate and fixed brackets):

```
var=NaN(1,50);
for i = 1:n
    var(i,1:numel(strfind(A(i,:),[1 1]))) = strfind(A(i,:),[1 1])
end
```